# Search the _id inside an array with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the code:

```
usermodel.findOne({"imagen._id": req.params.id }, {imagen: 1}, function (err, imagen){

    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(req.params.id + '\n');
    console.log(imagen);

    res.send(imagen);

});
```

And this is the Schema:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

  user: String,
  imagen: [{ 

              title: String,
              name: String,
              author: String,


           }]

});
```

I'm trying to get an output like this:

```
{  title: 'DQ monstes',
   name: 'fooname.png',
   author: 'fooauthor',
}
```

But I get this:

```
{ _id: 50f41ccff405ef73c4000006,
imagen: 
 [ { title: 'Pokemon',
   name: 'random.png',
   author: 'fooauthor',
},
  { title: 'DQ monstes',
    name: 'fooname.png',
    author: 'fooauthor',
}
```

The `_id` at the beginning is the `req.params._id` that I'm looking for at the `usermodel.findOne`. And I receive this error too:

```
/Users/rodrie/Documents/node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:434
     throw err;
           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes a find will always return the full documents. If you need to modify the returned result extracting parts of it you need to use the aggregation framework http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/. However be advised that the aggregation framework does not return a cursor so if you are iterating over more than 16MB of documents it won't help you as it will return a single document with upto 16MB of results.